# Regex to ignore starting characters if repeating while fetching substring

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, regex-group

I am facing the issue in getting the substring using the regex.

I want to fetch all the substring enclosed inside the braces.

ex. abc {{{data1} xyz {data2}}`

I am using the `\\{.*?\\}` as a regex and getting the output as `{{{data1} {data2}`

I want the regex to give me output as `{data1} {data2}` (No extra braces in start of data1)

How can I achieve this? Is there any regex I can put?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `({[^{}]+})` to find out the matches. This will match anything between the braces, which are not `{}`.

```js
const str = 'abc {{{data1} xyz {data2}}';
console.log(str.match(/{[^{}]+}/g));
```

Comment: I am trying to use it in swift language but it is not working there. Also, it can contain anything in the braces like special characters.

'abc {{{*data1-data} xyz {data2}}'

Is there any other thing I have to do to work in swift?

Comment: It is working in swift also if I am putting like "\\{[^\\{\\}]+\\}".

Comment: @CodeCracker If you are using swift why did you tag [javascript] in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Match `{`, followed by word characters, followed by `}`:

```js
const str = 'abc {{{data1} xyz {data2}}';
console.log(str.match(/\{\w+\}/g));
```